# Detect the presence of the ie10 metro address bar with javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a site that has some call to action buttons in a div that is fixed to the bottom of the screen.

We are currently using a div that is positioned absolutely as follows

```
<div id="buttonBar">footer code</div>
<style>#buttonBar{ bottom: 0; width: 100%;  position: fixed; }</style>
```

This has worked well in all the browsers except for IE10 in metro (modern) mode.

When a link is clicked the address bar shows and covers the button bar, it then disappears

Other than redesigning the layout of the page, I would like the button bar to sit just above the address bar when it is shown.

Does anyone know a way of detecting whether the address bar is visible using javaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to move the footer above the location-bar, until the location-bar collapses, then drop the footer back down.  Here's a potential solution:

1.
Move your footer up 50px (or whatever) if the user is likely on an IE10 touch-enabled browser

```
if (!!window.navigator.msPointerEnabled) { // sniff for IE10 + touch
    $("#buttonBar").css("transform", "translateY(-50px)");
}
```

2.
Listen for the first interaction with the browser, then collapse the footer with the location-bar.

```
$("body").on("MSGestureStart MSInertiaStart MSGestureTap MSPointerDown", function () {
  $("body").off("MSGestureStart MSInertiaStart MSGestureTap MSPointerDown");
  $("#buttonBar").css("transform","translateY(0)");
});
```

---

This solution hasn't been 100% reliable, there are clearly some interactions that collapse the location-bar but don't trigger an event.  I'm working on a better solution and will update once found, but figured I'd share this to get the ball rolling.